# MYBB Warning [2] count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable - Line: 906

Tags: php, mybb

hi sorry if dublicate but i dont know how to fix this MyBB 1.8.15 error on PHP 7.24
Warning [2] count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable - Line: 906

```
    // Build the threaded post display tree.
    $query = $db->query("
        SELECT p.username, p.uid, p.pid, p.replyto, p.subject, p.dateline
        FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."posts p
        WHERE p.tid='$tid'
        $visible
        ORDER BY p.dateline
    ");
    while($post = $db->fetch_array($query))
    {
        if(!$postsdone[$post['pid']])
        {
            if($post['pid'] == $mybb->input['pid'] || ($isfirst && !$mybb->input['pid']))
            {
                $postcounter = count($postsdone);
                $isfirst = 0;
            }
            $tree[$post['replyto']][$post['pid']] = $post;
            $postsdone[$post['pid']] = 1;
        }
    }

    $threadedbits = buildtree();
    $posts = build_postbit($showpost);
    eval("\$threadexbox = \"".$templates->get("showthread_threadedbox")."\";");
    $plugins->run_hooks("showthread_threaded");
}
```

Line 906 what gives error is `$postcounter = count($postsdone);`

Answer (score 0):

This error would occur if $postsdone were not evaluated to be "Countable" (in this case if it were not an array.) I would verify that $postsdone is an array before executing count($postsdone). For example:

```
if(is_array($postsdone)){
   $postcounter = count($postsdone);
}
else{
   // set $postcounter to whatever you want it be...
}
```